# Footnotes with italicized letters

Tags: footnotes, italic

I would like to use italicized superscript letters for footnotes rather than numbers. How could I do this? Example:

> This is text.<sup>*a*</sup> And more text.<sup>*b*</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>*a*</sup>  Footnote 1.
>
> <sup>*b*</sup>  Footnote 2.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can simply redefine the command `\thefootnote` which is responsible of the footnote superscript.

Either

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textit{\alph{footnote}}}
```

or

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\emph{\alph{footnote}}}
```

should be fine (anyway don't use the latter if you're loading packages like `ulem` that redefine the meaning of `\emph`!):

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textit{\alph{footnote}}}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

This is text.\footnote{Footnote 1.} And more text.\footnote{Footnote 2.}

\end{document}
```

[image]